# How can I get input from the user and check if part of it is a key in my dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, input

I need to get input from the user and check if the word following 'city' is inside of my dictionary (the key).

This is my dic:

```
mydic = {'Paris':132, 'Rome':42, 'San Remo':23}
```

I need the user to write 'city' (they will do so, given instructions that I gave them) but after it they have to write a city name. So they will write something like: 'city paris' and that has to return: 'Paris has 132 churches' or if they write 'city san remo' it has to return: 'San remo has 23 churches'.

The code has a conditional because if the user types 'city gba' then it returns a specific thing. So the issue is in the elif part where there are a lot more city options.

This is what I thought could work but doesn't for obvious reasons:

```
user_input = input().lower()

if user_input == 'city gba':
    print('City gba has', city_data.get('gba'), 'churches')
elif user_input.split() == 'city' + '':
        for x in user_input:
            if x in mydic.keys():
                print(x, 'has', city_data.get(x), ' churches.')
```

How else can I do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you aware that `.split()` returns a list? It will never be equal to a string. In your case `user_input.split()` will be `['city', 'paris']`. Maybe that can help you advance

Answer (score 2):

Your code is very close to working

```
user_input = input().lower() # Assume user input is "city Rome"

tag, city = user_input.split(" ", 1) # This will set tag = 'city' and city = 'rome'
if tag == 'city':
    if city.capitalize() in mydic: # You could also do mydic.keys() it doesn't matter
        print(f"{city} has {county_data.get(city)} churches.")
```

EDIT: `.split()`  does not work as cities like `united states` or `vatican city` are separated by spaces. We should use `.split(" ", 1)` which will only split on the first occurrence of a space.

Comment: Python has a `capitalize` method. I've updated my answer to use it

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have this code insde of a conditional so it gives me a syntax error because of the comma in 'tag, city', do you know if there's a way to put this in a conditional?

Comment: @satoru If you mean the `if user_input.split() == 'city' + '':` from your question than it simply shouldn't be in a conditional...

Comment: @Tomerikoo my code is bigger than this and there's some more possibilities to the input so one of them is if they type city and the name of the city so this is actually: elif tag, city (because this is one of the options)

Comment: @satoru Then the `split` should be before all conditions... It's hard to help without seeing the code...

Comment: @satoru could you send us the full code? I agree with tomerikoo

Comment: @satoru According to your edit, it seems like the target use-case for the new Python 3.10 feature [Structural Pattern Matching](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/)

Comment: @AmourK I edited the code so it will show what I meant.

Comment: Will your user input always be `"city <city name>"` or can it just be `"city"` or something else

Comment: @AmourK it's always the city and the name

Answer (score 1):

```
city, name = user_input.split(' ', 1)   # Extract "city" and the city name
if name.lower() in mydic.keys():
    print(x, 'has', county_data.get(x), ' churches.')
```

Note that you need the `name` and the key to be an exact match.  I recommend that you drop both to lower-case for the comparison.  Code the dict as all lower-case.

Answer (score 1):

Your use-case is exactly the point of the new Python 3.10 feature [Structural Pattern Matching](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/). So your code could be rewritten to:

```py
user_input = input().lower()

match user_input.split():
    case ['city', 'gba']:
        print('City gba has', city_data.get('gba'), 'churches')
    case ['city', city]:
        if city in mydict:
            print(city, 'has', city_data[city], 'churches.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as this should work.

**code**

```
#prompt user for city name
city = input('Enter a city. Format \'city name\': ')
#split user input at spaces. #['city','cityName']
#take the second element in this list
city = city.split()[1]
#check if that city is in the given dictionary. If so we print the cities church count.
if city in mydic.keys():print(f'{city} has {mydic[city]} churches')
#if it is not visible in the dictionary we show that city is not located in the given dictionary
else:print('City not in dictionary')
```

**input**

```
Enter a city. Format 'city name': city Paris
```

**output**

```
Paris has 132 churches
```